# Error don't know how to turn this value into a node

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am trying to test my .vue file and js files inside my NuxtJS project by running npm run test and I get this error.

```
 PASS  test/websocket.spec.js
 FAIL  test/Logo.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/components/Logo.vue: don't know how to turn this value into a node

      at valueToNode (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/valueToNode.js:87:9)
      at Object.valueToNode (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/valueToNode.js:81:58)
      at Object.exit (node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/dist/visitor.js:641:30)
      at PluginPass.exit (node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js:158:38)
      at newFn (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:179:21)
      at NodePath._call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
      at NodePath.call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
      at NodePath.visit (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:99:8)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitSingle (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
      at TraversalContext.visit (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
      at Function.traverse.node (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
      at traverse (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:66:12)
      at transformFile (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:107:29)
          at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
      at run (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:12)

Running coverage on untested files...Failed to collect coverage from /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/components/Logo.vue
ERROR: /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/components/Logo.vue: don't know how to turn this value into a node
STACK: Error: /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/components/Logo.vue: don't know how to turn this value into a node
    at valueToNode (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/valueToNode.js:87:9)
    at Object.valueToNode (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/valueToNode.js:81:58)
    at Object.exit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/dist/visitor.js:641:30)
    at PluginPass.exit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js:158:38)
    at newFn (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:179:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:99:8)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at traverse (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:66:12)
    at transformFile (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:107:29)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:12)
Failed to collect coverage from /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/pages/index.vue
ERROR: /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/pages/index.vue: don't know how to turn this value into a node
STACK: Error: /Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/pages/index.vue: don't know how to turn this value into a node
    at valueToNode (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/valueToNode.js:87:9)
    at Object.valueToNode (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/valueToNode.js:81:58)
    at Object.exit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/dist/visitor.js:641:30)
    at PluginPass.exit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js:158:38)
    at newFn (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:179:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:99:8)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at traverse (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:66:12)
    at transformFile (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:107:29)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/zup/Desktop/code/ACTIVE/coinhexa_v3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:12)
```

My jest.config.js file looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/server/**/*.js',
  ],
}
```

- If I set collectCoverage: false, I dont get the above error

Here is the dependencies section of my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.11.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-beta.20",
    "connect-redis": "^4.0.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-pino-logger": "^5.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "node-pg-migrate": "^5.1.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.12.2",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "pg-promise": "^10.5.6",
    "pino-pretty": "^4.0.0",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "ws": "^7.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.9",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "stylelint": "^13.6.0",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  }
```

- I tried downgrading vue-jest to ^3.0.5 as per the [ISSUE HERE](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10089) but then I get babel-core module not found error. I tried installing it but it gives another error.
- Any suggestions are super appreciated

Comment: were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @user805981 i tried searching a lot and couldnt find anything but I turned COLLECTCOVERAGE = false and then it works, hate it but what else can be done